# PDF File from Internet is not printable

Tags: pdf

I have an PDF File as download from the Internet and reading is no Problem,
but printing is not possible, ever an white paper came out of the printer.
Had anyone an idea ??
sorry for my bad english....

Comment: There are tons of reason this might be the case.  Does the page show up if you do a print preview?

Comment: Is this a public PDF file? If so can you edit the URL into your question?

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file has blocked printing of the document. Check the properties of PDF file for the permission allowed